# Difficulties with 'Either e` instance of `Failure` from "failure" package

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

This is more or less a simplified version of the issue I'm trying to understand in my own code. I'm working with functions that are polymorphic in the `Failure` class from [this package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/failure-0.2.0).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Either
import Control.Failure

data FookError = FookError deriving Show

fook :: (Failure FookError m)=> Int -> m Int
fook = undefined

fooks :: (Failure FookError m)=> Int -> m Int
-- DOES NOT TYPE-CHECK:
--fooks n = return $ head $ rights $ map fook [1..]
-- OKAY:
fooks n   = return $ head $ catMaybes $ map fook [1..]
```

You can see in the above code, that when I treat the return type of `fook` as `Maybe Int` the module compiles fine, however treating it as `Either Fook Int` fails.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, in the non-working definition of `fooks`, `fook`'s type is ambiguous. When you use `catMaybes`, it disambiguates as `Maybe Int`, but when you use `rights`, it can be `Either e Int` for *any* `e`, and the compiler doesn't necessarily know which. Sure, by default the only `Failure` instance for `Either` is `instance Failure e (Either e)`, but there's nothing stopping you defining, e.g. `instance Failure String (Either Int)`.

If you explicitly specify the type by defining `fooks` as

```
fooks n =
  return $ head $ rights $ map (fook :: Int -> Either FookError Int) [1..]
```

then it works fine.

However, I suspect that you're not doing what you really want here; `fooks` never actually uses the failure capability of the underlying monad; indeed, even if there are no non-failing results, the monadic action still succeeds and returns a value. The value just so happens to be an error, but that's still probably not what you want :)

If you want `fooks` to try a bunch of individual `fook`s in turn, and return the first one that succeeds, then something like:

```
fooks :: (Failure FookError m, MonadPlus m) => Int -> m Int
fooks n = foldr mplus (failure FookError) $ map fook [1..]
```

should do the trick. The plain `Failure` class by itself offers no way to recover from errors, so you need to require `MonadPlus` too. Note that the `failure FookError` here will never actually be used, since `[1..]` is infinite, but presumably you're planning to change the definition; say to one that actually uses `n` :)

Unfortunately, that isn't all! `Either e` doesn't have a `MonadPlus` instance, presumably because there's no reasonable value of `mzero` (although another potential problem is that `mplus (Left e) (Left e')` could be either `Left e` or `Left e'`).

Thankfully, it's easy to define an instance for our specific type:

```
instance MonadPlus (Either FookError) where
  mzero = failure FookError
  mplus a@(Right _) _ = a
  mplus (Left _) a = a
```

You'll need `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}` at the top of your file to do this.

Comment: Thanks, ehird. That does the trick for this example, but the type annotation doesn't fix my issue in my original code (which has some complicating factors). I'll try to come up with a better example. And thanks for the specifics you give, but unfortunately this was just a toy example to try to demonstrate the error (unfortunately not a very good one).

Comment: voted to close, since I'm not sure this will help anyone, and I don't think I'll be able to come up with a good example of my issue tonight.